# Why doesn't CasperJS' sendAJAX function send any content for PUT requests?

Tags: javascript, casperjs, put

I want to update a JSON object though my app using the PUT method. I am attempting to partially simulate the operation of a form submission. This call is synchronous, as after the PUT, a 200 should be returned. However, when I try the code below, sendAJAX does not include the object's content, the PUT request has content-length: 0. A submission through the form has all of the correct settings - content-type, x-requested-with, etc. I'm not quite sure why the code below doesn't function as I'm expecting. I've also tried setting var 'data' as a string of json formatted parameters. That also results in a PUT request of content-length: 0.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll("h6");
    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        if (element[i].innerHTML == "Special Tag") {
            var appid = element[i].parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("app-id");

            var wsurl = "https://appurl.net"+appid;
            var data = new Object();
            data.user_id = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";
            data.name = "Name";
            data.description = "blahr blahr blahr";
            data.amount = "-9000000";
            data.start = 1409900400000;
            data.finish = 1412492400000;
            data.seq = 0;
            data.locked = false;
            data.paused = false;
            data.contributed_amount = 0;
            data.created = 1409920472782;
            data.modified = 1426538857339;
            data.color = "#E37368";
            data.archived = false;
            data.target_amount = null;
            data.uuid = "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx";
            data.aprox_daily_contribution = 0;
            return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(wsurl, "PUT", data, false, { contentType: "application/json"}));
```

Comment: 1. It doesn't look like you're using the `sendAJAX()` response. How do you know that the content is empty? Do you by any chance look at the `casper.on("resource.received", function(res){...});` event output? 2. Check that exactly the same request is sent. Maybe there are headers that are present during form submission which aren't present during the XHR. Use for example wireshark to compare those requests.

Comment: I am using resource.sent and resource.received. My goal is to simulate a form submission, though for right now, I just want to generate a similar PUT Request to the form action. When I see the resource.sent, the content-length header is set to 0. I have a capture of the form action's request. The server responds with a 500 if there is incomplete or missing information in the request. My sendAjax() assembles the PUT request without including the 'data' object, and the server responds with a 500 "no content". I hope this clarifies my issue somewhat. thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CasperJS' [`sendAJAX()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#sendajax) function does not support PUT requests as seen in the [code](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/bb706acdf38f30d2380ebd3897ba1d4cee74430c/modules/clientutils.js#L799):

```
xhr.send(method === "POST" ? dataString : null);
```

Or more precisely, it only supports a payload for POST requests. You will have to build the XHR yourself or change the CasperJS code accordingly.

---

I don't think you need to simulate the form submission. If you're testing the web app, then it is better to actually submit the form and then check if it resulted in a correct page rather than parsing the response, because you will need to effectively implement the logic twice: in the page JavaScript and in your test script.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I am working on a small framework for an in-house application that fuzzes parameters sent to our backend service. I want to bypass front-end validators when appropriate. This was essentially my first attempt at writing a convenient method for testing application parameters. With a form submission, I will have to capture the XMLHTTPRequest using a wrapper function, and modify the the request on the fly. I have code for this, but I was really hoping I could at least get a basic proof of concept using sendAJAX PUT.

Comment: I see. It's easy enough simply using XMLHttpRequest directly instead of sendAJAX.